# Fault in heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: experimental-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Suppose there is a point A . From 1 metre above of A , I throw a ball
. Clearly the velocity of ball at point A will be :
V = (2gh)½ = 6.29 m/s
Hence , I know position of ball ( at A ) along with the velocity as calculated above . Hence , heisenberg uncertainty principle failed here as I could simultaneously knew the position and velocity of ball when it reaches A .
Please point if I am wrong .

Comment: In classical mechanics there is no uncertainty principle. In quantum mechanics there is. You are describing classical mechanics.

Comment: Note that Heisenberg principle is about the precision, you may be able to carry some kind of experiment like that but how sure you can be that it started in exactly point A? If it is very precise what was its speed at point A?

Comment: Ok , as per you , let the speed at A not be exactly 6.29 m/s . Then , it's speed will be surely in range between (say) 5 m/s to 7 m/s , which definitely leads that even though there is uncertainty , but it's not as similar to h/2π as stated in the principle

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out the Heisenberg uncertainty principle does not apply to macroscopic objects like a ball, but we could change your experiment so you drop an electron rather than a ball. The HUP certainly applies to electrons.

The problem is that you are assuming:

1. you know exactly where you dropped the electron
2. you know exactly what the initial velocity was (i.e. zero)

and the problem is the HUP prevents you from knowing the position and velocity precisely at the same time. If you knew you dropped the electron **exactly** $1$m  above $A$ then you cannot know its velocity. Likewise if you knew it was **exactly** at rest then you cannot know its position. And this uncertainty in the initial state of the electron means its velocity will be uncertain when it reaches the point $A$.

Comment: Can you please tell that why we can't know the position of an object even if it's at rest ?

Comment: Then shouldn't the uncertainty principle be modified for a single quantity by stating that instead of two , even a single quantity can never be measured with certainity at any time?

Answer (score 2):

As @JonCuster said in the comments, Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle only works at the quantum level. In normal circumstances (classical mechanics), this rule does not apply. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I thought it hold for everything

Comment: Because we are often given textbook problems involving macro world also .

Comment: @Abbas It does technically apply to the macro world, but it is so insignificant that we normally ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle has many forms, but the one most appropriate to this thought experiment is

$$\Delta x \Delta p \ge \frac{h}{4\pi}$$

where $\Delta x$ is the uncertainty in position, $\Delta p$ is the uncertainty in momentum, and $h$ is Planck's constant.

If we ignore relativistic effects, the uncertainty in the momentum of an object is  its mass times the uncertainty of its velocity.

$$\Delta p = m\Delta v$$

Combining these two, we get

$$m\Delta x\Delta v \ge \frac{h}{2\pi}$$

From this, we can conclude that the larger the mass of an object, the smaller must be the minimum $\Delta x\Delta v$. That is, we can have less and less uncertain results, the more massive the object.

The mass of an object the size of a ball used in human sports is many orders of magnitude larger than the mass of an atom or a sub-atomic particle. As a result, the uncertainty in $\Delta x\Delta v$ is many orders of magnitude smaller than the uncertainty seen on the atomic scale.

Thus, *for practical purposes* we can *ignore* Heisenberg uncertainty on the scale of human sports. If we treat a number of phenomena, such as Heisenberg uncertainty, as *insignificant*, the resulting physics matches that which we know as classical mechanics. However, historically, classical mechanics arose *in ignorance* of certain phenomena such as Heisenberg uncertainty. Because the effects of these phenomena were small at the scale of human activities of the time, these effects were not *noticed* during the time period that classical mechanics was developed.

Comment: I like that answer a lot because (in contrast to other answers) it highlights the fact that the Heisenberg Principle also applies to macroscopic objects.